# JQuery ON binding to children with certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, children

I am using ON to bind the change event to future elements dynamically created. The DOM structure might be simplified but for now I wish to figure out how to correctly get the handler to fire on certain dynamic descendants of the static parent.

```
jQuery("#staticParent").on("change", "someSelector", myChangeFunction);
```

I need to figure out the "someSelector"...

The html structure is

```
<div id="staticParent">
     //Static elements too
     <p id="PC"><span><input class="PV" value="Hello from 1"/></span></p>
     //Dynamic elements
     <p><span><input class="PV" value="Hello from 2/></span></p>

</div>
```

If I change the input with start value "Hello from 2" how do I get the selector right in the ON handler above?

```
 someSelector should be "p > span > input.PV"
```

But no joy...
Any thoughts? Nick.

EDIT - If I change #staticParent to body and someSelector to input.PV then it works. Just has to check a lot more elements that way and seems suboptimal. i.e. I've made it work but not sure why the other way doesn't...

Comment: Why not just make the selector `"input.PV"`? Or have you tried `"p span input.PV"`?

Comment: You need to be careful. the .on() call only binds handler to EXISTING elements, so all DOM elements added after the call will not be binded. In that sense you need to tell us how your dynamic elements are created as well.

Comment: Tried both (as in replacements for "someSelector") and neither fire the event...

Comment: @Edward - yes. So I bind to the staticParent (i.e. it's in the DOM from the start), but the dynamically created elements can be referenced in the someSelector part...Also See my edit in the question. Curious.

Comment: See my new edit - jQuery('body').on('change','input.PV',myFunction); works....

Comment: Then I don't get it. Why not just bind the handler directly to the input whenever you create it? e.g. $('input.PV').change(myChangeFunction);

Comment: @Edward - but it's not there yet. $('input.PV') doesn't refer to all the elements I need it to when the page first loads. There's only 1 element potentially when I load the page. I thought ON is supposed to work on elements that will be created that fit the selector criteria...

Comment: Can you tell what is there initialize and what will be eventually added to the DOM?

Comment: @Edward : The elements after the // comment 'Static elements too are the static elements. The elements after the comment 'dynamic elements' are the dynamic elements. The latter are added by JS by various button click events.